# List of possible Exceptions per SQL-Command

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, plsql

I'm looking for a List of all possible exceptions which can occur for each SQL Command.
For example: If I have the following code:

```
Procedure p1
as
  l_cnt number;
Begin
  Select count(*)
    Into l_cnt
    From xyz;
Exceptions
  When ... Then
    ...
End;
```

Now I'm wondering which exception can occur in this Select Into Statement. I know a few but are they all there is? That's why I'm looking for an overview of possible Exceptions per SQL.

A question on top would be: Is it recommended to catch all possible Exceptions raised by SQL Code inside PLSQL?
I know of "when others" which is the only way for me atm to catch "unknown" exceptions.
Of course if the list of possible exceptions for a SQL is very long I would only handle the relevant exeptions and catch the others by "when others".

Comment: @MitchWheat, unknown table, column etc.

Comment: @jarlh: if the table isn't there you can't compile the procedure and if you drop the table after creating the procedure, the procedure becomes invalid and you can't execute it.

Comment: My comment was regarding if a select can raise an error. Answer to "how does a select raise an error?".

Comment: Okay maybe Select count wasnt the best example but the fact that you are arguing about errors which can occur proves my point. A list of exeptions per SQL would be great!

Comment: @jarlh: a missing table or column is NOT an execution error.

Comment: @MitchWheat, sorry, you're right about that. (But a cast error may occur, or divison by zero, or similar.)

Answer (score 1):

To be honesty, your question is pretty common.

For example, you query can lead to the following exceptions:

- **TIMEOUT_ON_RESOURCE** - A time out occurs while the database is waiting for a resource
- **STORAGE_ERROR** - PL/SQL ran out of memory or memory was corrupted

I would suggest to learn predifined exceptions from [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/errors.htm#i9355) and select suitable for each case.

Comment: I know this list. But not every Exception mentioned there can occur on every Statement right? So how do I filter to e.g. Select Into which should get me the ones you listed.

Comment: for your example, I wouldn't use specific exaptions 
No_data_found and to_many_rows are most used 
Rarly - %_cursor, index_dub_value, invalid number, zero_devide

Comment: other, can be used only in really specific cases.